# How do I get the selected items from a multi-select listbox in order that they were selected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox, multi-select

I have web application in which i populate listbox using items from database on page load.

I get the all items from listbox that are selected but they are in order in which they populated.

I want these items to be in the order that they are selected by user.

I tried `.change(function()` using jQuery but it returns only first selected items value.

I attaching my code for reference. I have used listbox using http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

This is my listbox:

```
   <asp:ListBox ID="dr_menuitem" runat="server" class="chzn-select" SelectionMode="Multiple" style="width:300px;" >
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
               </asp:Listbox>
```

This is the jQuery I call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {

               $('#dr_menuitem').change(function() {

                     alert($("#dr_menuitem option:selected").val());
                   });
           });

    </script>
```

Comment: You need to keep track of changes, see this question for some ideas on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308460/getting-the-newest-selected-options-text-from-multiple-select-list

Comment: i needed the same thing.. i wanted to know the last selected option which i found @[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308460/getting-the-newest-selected-options-text-from-multiple-select-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308460/getting-the-newest-selected-options-text-from-multiple-select-list).. credit goes to mark..

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value in selected order try this:

```
$("#dr_menuitem").change(function() {

   // $(this).val() will give you an array
   // of selected value in order
   // you've selected

   alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/550/)**

Comment: that will get all of the selected options, but not in the order that they were clicked.

Comment: @SamTyson hi mate, if you go through all demo, you'll see that they are giving value in order.

Comment: the idea in question is that I could click on the last option, then the first, and get a result of that sequence - not the order of predefined selections.

Comment: @thecodeparadox,Sorry for late reply. i have checked your code and it work fine it gives me the values selected in listbox but they are not in order in which user select ,they are in order as per listbox.thanks for help can u give solution on this one

Answer (score -2):

Try this jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#listbox").multiselect();
});
```

Comment: What is multiselect?  This doesn't exist in the jquery docs. I think your thinking of some king of plugin.

Comment: If you want to use this approach, this solution is missing this library: http://loudev.com/ maybe you can add it. I'll help you increase your reputation.